# Limit DocuSign ListStatusChanges to envelopes created by the application id

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am pinging a docusign account that has over 10k envelopes returned by ListStatusChanges for the 30 days.  Note: this is just an initial scan, after that, the time frame shrinks to the last scan + 3 minutes as suggested by DocuSign.

I know only 1 envelope was created by the application ID during that time frame.   How can I restrict results to the current application only?  I don't want all the envelopes for the account.

```
public EnvelopesInformation GetEnvelopesInformation(DateTime fromDate)
{
    CheckToken();

    EnvelopesInformation envelopeInfo = null;
    string fromDateStr = fromDate.ToString("o");

    EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions options = new EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions()
    {
        fromDate = fromDateStr,
        fromToStatus = DocusignUtilities.StatusStrings.SIGNED, // excludes delivered, created, and sent envelopes
    };

    // |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to envelopes and envelope recipients
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(ApiClient.Configuration);
    envelopeInfo = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(AccountID, options);

    return envelopeInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is your application can use a custom field to identify itself `("myAppMarker")`.
The code above could be modified like this:

```
public EnvelopesInformation GetEnvelopesInformation(DateTime fromDate)
{
    CheckToken();

    EnvelopesInformation envelopeInfo = null;
    string fromDateStr = fromDate.ToString("o");

    EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions options = new EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions()
    {
        customFiled = "myAppMarker",
        fromDate = fromDateStr,
        fromToStatus = DocusignUtilities.StatusStrings.SIGNED, // excludes delivered, created, and sent envelopes
    };

    // |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to envelopes and envelope recipients
    EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(ApiClient.Configuration);
    envelopeInfo = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(AccountID, options);

    return envelopeInfo;
}
```

Comment: Works as a going forward solution, but I would prefer a solution that works for envelopes that were already created by the application.